# No visable Difference between two Lists for Visualisation via Palette creating an Error

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, classification, list

I want to Visualize a Landcover Classification

I have different success with seemingly identical Lists.

**List 1**:
Pallette Parameters inside the Code  like:

`var landcoverPalette1 = [
'E6004D',   //Artificial surfaces > Urban fabric > Continuous urban fabric
'FF0000'    //Artificial surfaces > Urban fabric > Discontinuous urban fabric
]`

**List2**: 
Palette Obtained via Code

`var landcoverPalette = ee.List(lc2012.get('landcover_class_palette'))`

**List1** and **List2** are identical withing the `print()` statement([see Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0bc7766adaf77878d281e4b70dc453a2)), but **List2** generates an Error

`2012: Layer error: Image.visualize: Expected a string or list of strings for field 'palette'.`

[Code without Error](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0bc7766adaf77878d281e4b70dc453a2)

[Code with Error](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9c8b2bd8557f84962a29f0dafbac6400)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing client-side and server-side objects, see [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server).

You will need to make the visualization a server-side object (namely, a dictionary):

```
var landcoverPalette = ee.List(lc2012.get('landcover_class_palette'))

var landcoverVisualization= ee.Dictionary({palette: landcoverPalette, min: 0, max: 44, format: 'png'});
```

[full link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/412a738182b1c0f339828a6e22df80b0)